# 'User' object has no attribute 'allow_add_item'

Tags: python-2.7, django-models, django-1.8

I tried to extend my user model with the following profile model, but I get an Attribute Error

> User' object has no attribute 'allow_add_item

My app model has the following class. Please tell me which corrections are needed.

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="dcf_profile")
    phone = models.CharField(_('phone'), max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    receive_news = models.BooleanField(_('receive news'), default=True, db_index=True)
    def allow_add_item(self):
        if self.item_set.count() > settings.DCF_ITEM_PER_USER_LIMIT:
            return False
        else:
            return True

class Item(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, verbose_name=_('group'))
    title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(_('description'))

    price = models.DecimalField(_('price'), max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    phone = models.CharField(_('phone'), max_length=30)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('display'), default=True, db_index=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(_('updated'), auto_now=True, db_index=True)
    posted = models.DateTimeField(_('posted'), auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('item')
        verbose_name_plural = _('items')
        ordering = ('-updated', )
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('item', kwargs={
            'pk': self.pk,
            'slug': self.slug
        })
    def get_title(self):
        return u'%s' % self.title
    def get_description(self):
        return u'%s' % self.description[:155]
    def get_keywords(self):
        # TODO need more optimal keywords selection
        return ",".join(set(self.description.split()))
    def get_related(self):
        # TODO Need more complicated related select
        return Item.objects.exclude(pk=self.pk)[:settings.DCF_RELATED_LIMIT]
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.slug is None:
            self.slug = slugify(unidecode(self.title))
        super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

My views.py contains :

```
@method_decorator(login_required)
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.request.user.allow_add_item():
        messages.error(self.request, _('You have reached the limit!'))
        return redirect(reverse('my'))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell for sure, because the code you have posted has indentation errors other than the one you are asking about.

But your message indicates that you haven't defined the method you are trying to call. If you want your class `CustomUser` to have a method `allow_add_item()` then the method definition must be inside the class. What I see is a line of code that calls `post_save.connect()` and the definition of `allow_add_item()` only after that. If you do that, it isn't a member of the class, it is just a function with the misleading argument `self` that makes it look like a method.

You need to indent it to put it inside the class definition. And not have extraneous code in between.

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    ...
    def allow_add_item(self):
        if self.item_set.count() > settings.DCF_ITEM_PER_USER_LIMIT:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Comment: I have updated my question above, could you please tell me the solution because I still get the same AttributeError message.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that every user always has a CustomUser attached to it, what you need to change is `self.request.user.allow_add_item()` to `self.request.user.customuser.allow_add_item()`

your CustomUser does not replace the regular User, it expands on it through the one to one relationship.

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Comment: It displays RelatedObjectDoesNotExist error ( 
User has no customuser) , it seems that it is related to reverse foreignkey relationships. Please help me find a solution.

Comment: on the OneToOneField parameters try adding reverse_name='custom_user', and then use request.user.custom_user

Comment: I have updated the related_name (not reverse_name) but I get RelatedObjectDoesNotExist error. Please see the Item class above and the user field and tell me what to do. I guess a relation is needed between the CustomUser and the Item tables